# C++ linked list implementation, goes to infinite loop while traversing. Guessing something is wrong with the contructors

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++. I'm trying to implement a linked list. The output goes to an infinite loop when the traverse function is called(output shown at the bottom). Had no errors when I used 'new' in the insertNodeAtEnd function instead of contructors, but I read up that it's generally not a good practice in C++ and it's better to get accustomed to using constructors.
What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>

struct Node
{
    int data;
    Node *next;
    Node(int data)
    {
        this->data = data;
        this->next = NULL;
    }

    ~Node() {}
};

class LinkedList
{
  public:
    LinkedList()
    {
        std::cout << "Linked list created \n";
    }

    static Node *head;
    static Node *tail;
    static int numberOfNodes;

    static int getNumberOfNodes()
    {
        return numberOfNodes;
    }

    static void insertNodeAtEnd(int data)
    {
        Node newNode(data);
        if (head == NULL)
        {
            head = tail = &newNode;
            return;
        }

        tail->next = &newNode;
        tail = &newNode;
        numberOfNodes++;
        return;
    }

    static void traverse()
    {
        if (numberOfNodes == 0)
        {
            std::cout << "Linked list is empty \n";
        }
        Node *curr = head;
        while (curr != NULL)
        {
            std::cout << curr->data << std::endl;
            curr = curr->next;
        }
        return;
    }

    ~LinkedList()
    {
        std::cout << "Linked list destroyed \n";
    }
};

Node *LinkedList::head = NULL;
Node *LinkedList::tail = NULL;
int LinkedList::numberOfNodes = 0;

int main()
{
    LinkedList linkedlist;
    linkedlist.insertNodeAtEnd(40);
    linkedlist.insertNodeAtEnd(50);
    linkedlist.insertNodeAtEnd(60);
    linkedlist.insertNodeAtEnd(70);
    linkedlist.traverse();
}
```

And here's the output. (Infinite loop, had to terminate in the console.)

```
Linked list created 
70
70
70
70
70
70
70
```

Comment: `static Node *head; static Node *tail; static int numberOfNodes;` -- Why the static member variables?  These should be non-static.

Comment: `head = tail = &newNode;` In `insertNodeAtEnd`, you are using the address of a local variable. Use `new` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
static void insertNodeAtEnd(int data)
{
    Node newNode(data);
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        head = tail = &newNode;
        return;
    }

    tail->next = &newNode;
    tail = &newNode;
    numberOfNodes++;
    return;
}
```

`newNode` is a function local variable. Its lifetimes ends when the function returns. The pointers you store are dangling. When you dereference them later you invoke undefined behavior.

To dynamically allocate the nodes, such that they persist you can do

```
Node* newNode = new Node(data);
```

It is not clear why all members of `LinkedList` are declared `static`. The effect is basically that you can only have one linked list, because a second one would share all members.

Comment: Understood, thanks. So at the end of the function, I have to delete the 'newNode' right?. Regarding the static, I thought it would be good to have only ONE linked list with multiple nodes in it.

Comment: @fghtclb no, if you do that you are still storing dangling pointers. You should delete the nodes in the lists destructor

Comment: Won't the Node destructor take care of that?

Comment: @fghtclb the `Node` destructor is called when you call `delete some_node;` but someone has to do that

Comment: All worked, thanks. Regarding the destructor, why is the linked list destructor called when I haven't called delete on it?

Comment: @fghtclb because `LinkedList linkedlist;` has automatic storage duration, its destructor is called when it goes out of scope. This is the most coolest feature of C++, its sad that beginners get troubled with dynamic allocation before understanding the much more important concept. RAII is another buzzword you can read about.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by instead creating a new Node rather than directly instantiating one. What happens in your version is that the created node is destroyed while by creating a new one it will remain valid until explicitly deleted

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct Node
{
    int data;
    Node *next;
    Node(int data)
    {
        this->data = data;
        this->next = NULL;
    }

    ~Node() {}
};

class LinkedList
{
  public:
    LinkedList()
    {
        std::cout << "Linked list created \n";
    }

    static Node *head;
    static Node *tail;
    static int numberOfNodes;

    static int getNumberOfNodes()
    {
        return numberOfNodes;
    }

    static void insertNodeAtEnd(int data)
    {
        Node* newNode = new Node(data);
        if (head == NULL)
        {
            head = tail = newNode;
            return;
        }

        tail->next = newNode;
        tail = newNode;
        numberOfNodes++;
        return;
    }

    static void traverse()
    {
        if (numberOfNodes == 0)
        {
            std::cout << "Linked list is empty \n";
        }
        Node *curr = head;
        while (curr != NULL)
        {
            std::cout << curr->data << std::endl;
            curr = curr->next;
        }
        return;
    }

    ~LinkedList()
    {
        std::cout << "Linked list destroyed \n";
    }
};

Node *LinkedList::head = NULL;
Node *LinkedList::tail = NULL;
int LinkedList::numberOfNodes = 0;

int main()
{
    LinkedList linkedlist;
    linkedlist.insertNodeAtEnd(40);
    linkedlist.insertNodeAtEnd(50);
    linkedlist.insertNodeAtEnd(60);
    linkedlist.insertNodeAtEnd(70);
    linkedlist.traverse();
}
```